# How to scan for all implementations of a generic type with Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

We are using the domain events pattern and leaning on our IoC container to locate handlers for a particular type of event:

```
public interface IHandleEvent<TEvent> where TEvent : IEvent
{
    void Handle(TEvent evnt);
}
```

With StructureMap we can scan and register all types implementing the above interface like so:

```
Scan(cfg =>
{
    cfg.TheCallingAssembly();
    cfg.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IHandleEvent<>));
});
```

Is there an equivalent with Ninject?

Currently I'm having to bind each handler individually like so:

```
kernel.Bind<IHandleEvent<SomeEvent>>().To<EventHandler1>();
kernel.Bind<IHandleEvent<SomeEvent>>().To<EventHandler2>();
kernel.Bind<IHandleEvent<SomeOtherEvent>>().To<EventHandler3>();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Ninject Conventions Extensions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions).
It provides a configuration by convention for Ninject. There is quite good documentation in wiki.

Answer (score 7):

The Ninject Conventions Extensions package did exactly what I need. The working code is below:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom(typeof(IHandleEvent<>))
    .BindSingleInterface());
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it for me. Btw, you're blog helped me a lot.